# Spinner selection to String

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, spinner

i have this code

```
go_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
              myIntent.putExtra("id", ed_txt.getText().toString());
              myIntent.putExtra("type", spinner.getText().toString());
              LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

i want the selected option in the spinner to my string.

this give me an error

```
myIntent.putExtra("type", spinner.getText().toString());
```

when i use

```
myIntent.putExtra("type", spinner.getContext().toString());
```

i am getting my package name.

how do i get my selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
myIntent.putExtra("type", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

instad of

```
myIntent.putExtra("type",spinner.getText().toString());
```

for getting selected item text from Spinner

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a listener to the spinner to get the selected item. It should be something like this

```
String selection = null;
//Initialise Spinner (you may have done this already)

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.[your spinner id]);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            selection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    })
```

You can then use put the "selection" string into your intent. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check for this code and i hope this code useful,

```
String getSelectItem = "null";
```

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.[your spinner id]);

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        getSelectItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```